# UIButton Not responding in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I select a button within a custom UITableViewCell, it does not respond to my touchevent.

[image: Code for creating the custom UITableViewCell]

Code that creates the custom UITableViewCell.  I have done a lot of research for a solution and I try to bring the button to the front of the contentview.

[image: Nib view]

Here is how it looks in IB.  Also, the tableview that host the custom UITableViewCell has userinteraction enabled along with the button and contentview. 
Update!
The button is clickable if its within the top 44 points aka the equivalent height of a normal UITableViewCell. However, WHen I click it I get this error.  I don't understand why it is only enabled for userinteraction within the first 44 points of its height. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just try

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    return THE_ACTUAL_HEIGHT_OF_CELL_THAT_IS_GREATER_THAN_DEFAULT_44;

}
```

Comment: This solves the issue with allowing the button to be clickable. But it still crashes with a BAD_ACCESS error. I guess its trying to reference a null object?  I have the Action in a header file take the button is suppose to be targeting.